# Best practice to populate XElement with some text that containes XML nodes inside

Tags: .net, xml, linq

what is the best way to populate XElement with the test that may contains not only the pure text but some XML nodes as well?

For example, this code

```
XElement el = new XElement("XML_NODE");
el.Value = "some text <TAG>with custom tag value</TAG>";
string xml = el.ToString();
```

will return xml as `<XML_NODE>some text &lt;TAG&gt;with custom tag value&lt;/TAG&gt;</XML_NODE>`. I understand what is going on and why it has happened. But it's not exactly what I want... I wish to get xml similar to this `<XML_NODE>some text <TAG>with custom tag value</TAG></XML_NODE>` where inner brackets are not quoted.

The desired result can be achieved by the next code

```
XElement el2 = XElement.Parse("<XML_NODE>some text <TAG>with custom tag value</TAG></XML_NODE>");
xml = el2.ToString();
```

but I don't like the idea to build XML as a string and parse it later.

Are there any other better ways to get it?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative which might be slightly more efficient:

```
static IEnumerable<XNode> ParseNodes(string value)
{
   var settings = new XmlReaderSettings 
   { 
      ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment 
   };

   using (var sr = new StringReader(value))
   using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
   {
      xr.Read();
      while (xr.ReadState != ReadState.EndOfFile)
      {
         yield return XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
      }
   }
}

string text = "some text <TAG>with custom tag value</TAG>";
var node = new XElement("XML_NODE", ParseNodes(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, there is really no better way. But you could encapsulate this "not so good" way somewhat:

```cs
public IEnumerable<XNode> ParsePartial(string partialXml)
{
    return XElement.Parse(string.Format("<tmp>{0}</tmp>", partialXml)).Nodes();
}

var el3 = new XElement("XML_NODE",
                       ParsePartial("some text <TAG>with custom value</TAG>"));
```

Comment: Hmm... I think it's much better... at least I like it more :) Why I didn't think about it from the beginning?! Thanks a lot! ;)